# .Net Core - React - TypeError: this.state.values.map is not a function - App.UseEndpoint

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am learning React and I have a working API that is fit for purpose and now needs a front end on it. At the moment, I am looking to prove that I can get the data out and that CORS policy is working as I would hope/expect.

As you will see from the image, I can hit the endpoint and in the console, I am seeing data.

[image]

At the moment this is my code that is although concept and not using React Hooks (that will be later down the line)

```
state = {
values: [],
};

componentDidMount() {
 axios.get('https://localhost:5001/get-countries').then((response) => {
   console.log(response);
   this.setState({
     values: response.data,
   });
   console.log(this.state.values);
 });
}
... ommitted code

<ul>
    {this.state.values.map((value: any) => (
    <li>
     ... more ommitted code
    </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

When I run this I get the error

> TypeError: this.state.values.map is not a function

The API is using Ardalis Endpoints and Mediatr Pattern which at this point cannot be changed because its part of a wider project.

So, the question is that how do I stop this from giving an error.

Comment: As far as I see, `state.values` does not hold an array, it holds the countries object. So you should change it to `state.values.countries.map(...`

Comment: @ibubi if I do that I get a compile error  Property countries does not exists on type never[]. I also cannot make values an array of ICountry

Comment: My mistake, you should assign countries like; `values: response.data.countries;` and keep the other line as it is, `state.values.map(...`

Comment: Youre a star thank you. If you could provide that as an official answer I can upvote the response and reward the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment,

Error indicates that the `state.value` data does not hold an array, you are assigning
countries object to the `state.value`. Instead you should do assign countries itself;

```
this.setState({
  values: response.data.countries,
});
```